# how to attach a EBS volume to my container using docker-compose.yml and ecs-cli

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am using `docker-compose.yml` to define a set of containers. And use `ecs-cli compose (service) up` to create my application on `AWS`.

I know `AWS ECS` comes with 100GB `EBS` automatically when a container is created. (Even though the `EC2` instance that hosts the container only have 8GB of hard drive.) 
I want to have a persistent storage so that even if I updated my container, it can still point to the same 100GB `EBS`. I am pretty sure I can do the following to achieve this goal:

> Attach an external `EBS` to the EC2 instance, and use `volume` in the
>   compose file to attach that volume to the container.

However, I feel there might be a better way to do so on ECS since it gives you 100GB ELB automatically. That is, if I use the above approach, then I am really 'wasting' the 100GB volume that comes with each container.
So, what is the best way to achieve this. Could you give an answer in the form of a docker-compose.yml format like the following?

```
container1:
  image: image1

container2:
  image: image2
  links:
    - "container1"
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already resolved this. Here is working `docker-compose.yml` for me.

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    volumes:
      - /var/ebsshare:/ebs
  container2:
    volumes_from:
      - container1:rw
```

Please make sure your EBS source path(/var/ebsshare) has necessary permissions so docker containers can read and write data to it (chmod 755?).

container2 shares volume from container1 with Read-Write(**rw**) permissions.